# Window maximization sizes wrong after RDP session

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

After remoting into my Windows XP box with Windows' built-in Remote Desktop, and then coming back to log in locally, I notice something is out of sorts with the applications I've left open.  Particularly, when I maximize the windows (or if they are already maimized) they stretch beyond the range of the desktop - usually, below the taskbar.  Even when I restore and re-maximize the windows, they continue to do this.  The only solution I've found so far is to log off and log in again.

What causes this?  Is there any way to prevent this, without requiring special (manual) steps for *every* remote session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the properties of your remote session shortcut to use a fixed display attribute that matches the host's diaplay settings. This happens a lot when you rdp from a pc with a larger screen resolution then the target host.

Comment: Is there any way to reset the windows *without* logging off? With my computer, a logoff/login cycle can take 10 minutes.